# How to access a particular label text in Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am using the following code in my `EditItemTemplate` of `GridView1`.

```
<EditItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="<%# bind('ftype') %>"></asp:Label>
    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="<%# bind('ftname') %>"></asp:Label>
    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="<%# bind('fsname') %>"></asp:Label></br>
    <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="<%# bind('fa1') %>"></asp:Label></br>
    <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text="<%# bind('fa2') %>"></asp:Label></br>
    <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text="<%# bind('fa3') %>"></asp:Label></br>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" Width="30px" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" Width="30px" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" Width="30px" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" Width="30px" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
 </EditItemTemplate>
```

Now in my `GridView1_RowEditing` function, I want to access the `Label4` text. I use `FindControl` but that only finds the control and didn't return the text.

```
protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    Label Label1 = (Label)GridView1.FindControl("Label4");
    if (Label1.Text == null)
    {
        //some code
    }
}L
```

How can I access the `text` of any `label` present in `Gridview`?

Comment: please share your row editing function

Comment: i have editaed my answer check this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this,

```
protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    Label label = (Label)this.GridView1.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].FindControl("Label4");
    string value = label.Text;
}
```